# Query filter with Like or Instr?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this situation. I have two tables that I have to bind through like.
I'll explain.
tab2 has a field with ids separated by;
I have to extract all the values of tab1 with id corresponding to the field in tab2

the query is as follows:

SELECT s.* FROM `tab1` s "
                        . "INNER Join tab2 on "
                        . "tab2.field Like Concat (\"%\",tab1.field,\";%\") "

Now I have a problem. In tab2 I have 1; 2; 14; 15 the result I get in the query is:
1
2
4
5
14
15
but actually lines 4 and 5 should not come out. I guess because of the Like %% there is no way to filter this?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on your data, and what you're trying to "find" with the query, a little more for this to make much sense.

Comment: are you telling me that I can not get data with this select? I'll explain. With the current selection I have some results, I need another filter on my own because with the current query it gives me the result of the combined rows. If the field of tab2 has this id: 1; 2; 3; 14; 15 the result on the board one must have 5 rows while the rows are seven because with the Like Concat %% for example the id 14 is worth 4 and 14. I would like to know if what can still be filtered out

Comment: I just saying you should show samples of your source data, and the desired output results. You can use the `{}` formatting button to preserve the arrangement of samples.

Comment: I have solved. Like Concat (tab1.field,\";%\") OR INSTR(c.idretplace,concat(\";\",tab1.field,\";\")) >0)